# How to use NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, database, date, core-data, nspredicate

I am building a core data application and need to fetch objects based on their date. These objects are displayed in a UITableView if their date is on the same day as a global "selectedDate" which the user can change and probably will quite often. The code for this is below:

```
-(NSDate *)dateByMovingToEndOfDay:(NSDate *)date {

    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents* parts = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:date];
    [parts setHour:23];
    [parts setMinute:59];
    [parts setSecond:59];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:parts];
}


-(NSDate *)dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay:(NSDate *)date {

    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents* parts = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:date];
    [parts setHour:0];
    [parts setMinute:0];
    [parts setSecond:0];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:parts];
}
```

My question is which approach would be more efficient:

Executing a fetch request every time the user changes the selected date and use a predicate to get only the objects whose date's are on the same day as the selectedDate

Or

Fetching all the managedObjects on startup, storing them in an array and then sort through the array every time the user changes the selected date, creating a new array with only the correct objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1, the predicated fetch on demand. It will (probably) take longer to process but, as your app grows and the number of objects grows, the fetch on demand approach will scale much better and won't result in your app crashing (low memory).

Consider using an `NSFetchedResultsController` and set the `fetchBatchSize` of the `NSFetchRequest`.